# saxon .net 9.7 Syntax error in regular expression: unrecognized flag 'n'

Tags: asp.net, saxon

I've created an ASP.net application and installed saxon-he using the nugget package manager. I would like to use the [n flag](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/matches.html) to Use the standard .NET regular expression engine, allowing native .NET regex syntax. This is supported on the .NET platform only.

However i'm getting the following error:

```
{"Syntax error in regular expression: unrecognized flag 'n'"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Michael on saxon mailing list:

> The code to support the "n" flag is there in the product, though I'm
>   not sure whether it has been recently tested.
>
> Note that the flag must be separated from standard flags by a
>   semicolon, e.g. flags="s;n" or flags=";n".
>
> I think that unlike other Saxon extensions this one is available in HE
>   without a license key.
>
> Note also that you can set the .NET regex engine as your default by
>   setting the configuration parameter
>   "http://saxon.sf.net/feature/defaultRegexEngine" to the value "N".

Michael Kay

the semi colon fixed the issue